# How can I convert an OpenAPIv3/swagger spec into a proxy around an API using Python and Prance library?

Tags: python, rest, swagger, openapi, dynamic-class-creation

I'm building an automatic proxy generator around any arbitrary API given it's swagger document. The intended output would be a python module that could be used as a client for said API. The API itself would import the proxy generator, point it at its own Swagger page and export the dynamically constructed python client as part of a module.

Currently I'm using the prance library to parse the swagger.json document into a nested-dict structure.

```
parser = ResolvingParser(swagger_url)
print(parser.specification.keys())
>> dict_keys(['openapi', 'info', 'paths', 'components'])
```

The paths key here contains most of the juicy bits as a nested dictionary. This can be thought of as a tree, where the root of the tree is the given api path. For example '/api/v1/products' and the rest of the dictionaries are describing details of this path given the OpenAPI spec.

My goal is to take this nested dictionary structure and produce a set of objects that can be used to dynamically create a proxy around the API. The end-goal is to have a structure similar to the below

```
class Schema:
""" This class would define the object that is going to be returned. aka schema)"""

class Parameter:
name: str
type: str
in: str (Example: query, path, etc.)

class Get(Method):
parameters: List[Parameter]
body: Body = None
return_schema: Schema

class Endpoint():
path: str
description: str
methods: List[Type[Method]]
```

I would use these objects to dynamically generate a set of methods on a proxy for each endpoint.

I've explored a couple different paths to achieve the goal but am getting stuck on how to best handle the data structure given to me via Prance. I have a vague notion that flattening the data-structure is the best way to continue but need some guidance after this point.

I've:

- Explored using `pd.json_normalize()` to normalize the json into a more usable format. This is promising but I'm unsure of how to continue
- Flattening the nested dictionary into one level where the keys are the path through the tree separated by `.`.
- Tried using the built in prance iterators (although I found them to be a bit obtuse to use)
- Tried using openapi-generator but it didn't work for my purposes, as well as the python client being outdated

I'm looking for resources on how I can continue development, given my goals and this data-structure I'm working with.

Although this is the current path I've decided to take, other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/swagger-ui-py/

Comment: This looks like its in the right area, although I don't know if it's exactly what I need. This looks like it is more related to editing of the document. Although presumably if it allows editing, it would parse the document in a more usable format. Do you have experience with this library @VisheshMangla? I'm a bit confused about the supported frameworks. Considering I'm parsing an OpenAPI spec it ought not matter which resource generated it. Fastapi, swashbuckler, etc. I should specify I'm looking to create a proxy client not a Proxy api

Comment: Nope, I haven't used it sorry.

Comment: Here's another thing  https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Comment: You can import your swagger in postman and it can give you the code. But I don't know if there is some api postman would provide to automate the stuff
See what chapgpt suggests : https://bpa.st/4VYQK . You need that tool "newman"

Comment: https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-codegen/ Also see this, I think this is what is helpful and not newman

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a standard parser for OpenAPI that is modeled similarly to the classes you described. I've been referring to the format as `OpenAPIIntermediateRepresentation` and you can see how the object is modeled in this [yaml file](https://github.com/fern-api/fern/blob/d6217cf1d5cc12ce0e24f27d1cd6b8a104f8753d/fern/openapi-ir/definition/ir.yml#L25-L42). The parser is open source and published under the npm package [@fern-api/openapi-parser](https://github.com/fern-api/fern/blob/d6217cf1d5cc12ce0e24f27d1cd6b8a104f8753d/packages/cli/openapi-parser/src/parseFile.ts#L14-L38).

For context, I work on an open source project called Fern and we are building an OpenAPI alternative but we also are compatible with existing OpenAPI documents. We have a python SDK generator that generates modern, idiomatic code. If you want to check it out, here are our docs: https://buildwithfern.com/docs/spec/openapi.